Error: invariant expected layout router to be mounted when running a nextjs app
I bootstrapped a nextJs project using nxp create-next-app-@latest and I keep getting this error when I run the project

Next.js (15.0.4) out of date (learn more)
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: invariant expected layout router to be mounted

I tried using nextJs version 14 and I get this error Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).. I believe it is from the same source, just different error messages
NOTE: NO FILE WAS EDITED. THE FILES ARE THE SAME AS WHEN THE ONES GENERATED BY nxp create-next-app-@latest COMMAND
I tried creating a nextJs app with different versions, I was expecting the code to run successfully and display the boilerplate.
